# How can I do a projection using a Grails 2.0 where query?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I like the new Grails 2.0 "where" queries but need to do a projection. Anyone know how? Right now I have code that instantiates all the domain instances and extracts the field I need:

```
List<Double> eloRatings = User.where { !deleted }.list()*.eloRating
```

This isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this blog post](http://blog.oio.de/2011/12/21/grails-database-queries-criteria-builder-vs-where-queries/), you can't use projections *directly* with `where` queries.  However, since the returned object from a `where` query is a `DetachedCriteria`, you can append a traditional criteria to it, like so:

```
List<Double> eloRatings = User.where { !deleted }.projections {
    property 'eloRating'
}.list()
```

This should work, I tested it under Grails 2.0.

Comment: That blog post is a winner! Some of that needs to go into the Grails docs.

Comment: Yeah, it's a really useful post.